# jQueryTools requires div for tooltip to be place after trigger element (li) -- document fails to validate

Tags: jquery-tools, w3c-validation

Here's the jQueryTools demo page on how to use their tooltips: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

Basically, if you want to have a tooltip that contains HTML, you have to put that HTML in a div and place it directly after the trigger element like so:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" id="link1">
<div class="tooltip">
   <img src="img/SOicon.png">stack<span style="font-weight:bold">overflow</span>
</div>
```

But my trigger element isn't `<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" id="link1">`.  It's an `<li>`, and my guess is that I can't put anything other than an `<li>` in the parent `<ul>`.  In other words, I can't place the  after the trigger element like I'm supposed to.

I've come up with a way to fix this (scrapping the unordered list with floated `<li>`s and switching over to floated divs) but figured I should probably consult the experts (you guys, of course!) before I got started on fixing the problem.

How would you guys fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's no problem to use another element outside your structure as tooltip target !

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li title="List Point 1">List Point 1</li>
    <li title="List Point 2">List Point 2</li>
    <li title="List Point 3">List Point 3</li>
</ul>

<!-- many other HTML ELements -->
<div id="mylist_tooltip"></div>
```

At the end put in your jQuery's ready() :

```
jQuery("#mylist li").tooltip({
    // target div
    tip: '#mylist_tooltip'
});
```

Read more in the [docu](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html) ;-)